# How can Goldmoon speak to Riverwind when he is dead?

Tags: dragonlance

I just finished reading the War of Souls trilogy, and i often wondered how Goldmoon can communicate with Riverwind. Is she imagining things or is there some magic going on? Possibly, she can speak to Riverwind's soul, however he died before Takhisis stole the world so that wouldn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh god its been over 10 years since I read this. I need to do so again. But I believe he actually died AFTER the Chaos War, which would mean his soul is stuck just like everyone elses. However, the answer to your question actually comes from books not written by Weis/Hickman(*The Silver Stair*). After the gods were banished, and there was no more magic, people started looking for some other "magical" power. They discovered "mysticism". Now, Goldmoon in her grief, branched off of mysticism and discovered "dark mysticism". She used this to communicate with Riverwind on several occasions.

Comment: i though Riverwind died in the original Chronicles?

Comment: He survived the chaos wars: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riverwind#Age_of_Mortals_series

Comment: Although apparently not for long... between a hereditary terminal illness and a red dragon. There is some mention of the "dark mysticism" including that Weis and Hickman adopted it, in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldmoon#The_Fifth_Age_series

Comment: So goldmoon is using a sort of necromancy which stems from mysticism?

Comment: @AricFowler: Yeah, he survived the Chaos War. And I wouldn't say it's necromancy, as that sort of insinuates that she can bring back the dead. But she only "talks" to him.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks Talking to the dead is part of necromancy, although you could also refer to it as Séance

Comment: Riverwind died like tanis during the upraising of the dragons if my memory is not incorrect.

Comment: @Thomas "We'll go out through the kitchen"?